# Cocos2d - Setting Device/Screen Orientation

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to the cocos2d API and have noticed that there are a few ways to set the screens orientation within the templates. I have not been able to figure out the correct way to set my orientation to LandscapeRight and keep it that way throughout the entire game. How do I change my orientation so that it maintains LandscapeRight? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify GameConfig.h from the cocos2d template.

```
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone
/* original code is kGameAutorotationUIViewController. */
```

And modify AppDelegate.m as well.

```
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
#else
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    /* original code is "Left". */
#endif
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer here has changed with cocos2d 2.0, as CCDirector is now a ViewController on iOS:

> CCDirector no longer supports device orientation. All autorotation and
>   device orientation is handled by RootViewController now. Fortunately,
>   [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] can be used in place of
>   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] deviceOrientation]. The enums are the
>   same, except that they begin with UI instead of CC.
>
> Forcing a specific orientation is a simple matter of returning YES
>   only to the desired orientation in the RootViewController method
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

[Choosing between Cocos2D v1.x & 2.x and Tips for updating to Cocos2D 2.0 at learn-cocos2d.com](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/01/choosing-cocos2d-version-updating-cocos2d-2-0/)

Answer (score 3):

Use this line:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:kkCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the RootViewController.m,search for the line

```
return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation ));
```

change it to

```
return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation ));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you added shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and not solved your problem

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

THEN
Try to add this line to appDelegate.m

```
[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];
```

Good Luck

Answer (score -2):

The correct answer - took me a while to find - is in the info.plist, change the supported interface orientations values, item 0 and item 1 have 4 possible values, Portrait (top home button) etc.