# Need help manipulating a template (wave attack from Cartoonsmart)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, templates, cocos2d-iphone

First off, I have zero knowledge in programming... Just thought I would say that first before I get bombarded with jargon right out of the gate haha. I am an illustrator, motion graphics artist and animator trying to make their first game. This game has all the artwork covered... I plan on re-designing everything 100% to not appear to look like Cartoonsmarts on any level.

THAT BEING SAD... lol

If you are not familiar with this template you can see a little overview of the Wave Attack template I purchased at https://vimeo.com/34988233#at=1

What I need to do to it:

1. rotate the game to where the enemies come from the right and the player stays on the left. This means changing the menu to be landscape on top.
2. turn the "waves" into levels... I want to have 5 worlds with 4 levels for each world. I have 5 different backgrounds to show the world changes.
3. add a new set of enemies every world change. I have the sprites all covered for each world.
4. add a menu screen! haha the template does not include one and just jumps straight into the game.
5. lastly I need to divide the worlds with an image slideshow fading from image to image, about 2-3 images in an illustrated comic book explaining the transition to the next world.

If anyone knows how to do these things or help me in any way whatsoever please contact me on Skype (the25thPixel) I did not expect to budget for this thinking it would be easy lol but I am willing to pay someone for their help.

I am also willing to do a trade with some illustrations, graphics, or animations on any project someone may be working on. My site is 25thPixel.com ... please take a look and see that I plan on really showcasing my skills with a fun game that looks awesome.

I am always available and will be working on graphics in the mean time. I hope to hear from some of you soon... I was recommended to this site by the creator of the template thru his tutorial videos so hopefully this is the right place to post.

Comment: This is not a place to hire programmers, you might consider posting this on  [careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: In reality it should have been two separate posts; the first part of the question is, for the most part, in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a freelancing/hiring site, though as you're really only asking for help rather than a complete project it's probably okay. In terms of learning how to do what you outlined, be prepared to invest a little bit more time in the project. Some of the things you want to do, such as changing the orientation of the game and menu to landscape and adding a main menu, should be fairly simple, though they are difficult to explain in the limited space on this site. Following beginner tutorials on Cocos2d is your best bet in my opinion.

Some examples that should help:

[Cocos2d - Setting Device/Screen Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792706/cocos2d-setting-device-screen-orientation)
(Game orientation)

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/creating-a-simple-menu-with-scene-transition-in-cocos2d/
(Main menu and different levels)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial
(**Best** resource for what you're looking for - should help you create multiple enemy types, and attain a basic understanding of the parts of your template)

Also, you probably already know that Google is your best friend. In case you're not sure what to look for though, a couple examples: (By the way, remember that your template is in Cocos2d and you should be looking for info on that in particular)

**Scenes** will allow you to create menus, "slideshow transitions" between worlds, etc. Very, very important.

**CCSprite** is what your ship and your enemies are most likely based on. Also used to add UI elements sometimes.

I hope you're able to accomplish what you're trying to do, and maybe gain some programming knowledge along the way. Also, excellent portfolio - you have some very impressive work.

Cheers,

XenElement