# How to set default screen orientation?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, screen-orientation

Somehow related to [Cocos2d - Setting Device/Screen Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792706/cocos2d-setting-device-screen-orientation) however I want to find a way to leave the default "allowed orientation" settings as is, but modify initial orientation setting.

Now:

- initial orientation: landscape left
- allowed orientations: any landscape

Desired:

- initial orientation: landscape right
- allowed orientations: any landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was suggested in this old post answer: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/32650

> If you support both landscape orientations but want to have
>   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft be the initial, then change the
>   code above to return
>   UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation) and in your
>   info.plist file, set the UIInterfaceOrientation (initial interface
>   orientation) key to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft.

It didn't work for me. Instead I changed the order of orientations in UISupportedInterfaceOrientations from "left, right" to "right, left" and now my game starts in landscape right but allows rotating to landscape left.